# how to simultaneously pass A model as well as a File to the controller?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

i have a **reports** model in my MVC project. Now i have to send a file to the controller simultaneously. I am using HttpPostedFileBase as parameter with my reports model. 
Reports Model is :

```
  Public Class ReportsModel
    Public Sub New()
        Authentication = "private"
    End Sub

    Private UploadDate_ As String

    <Display(Name:="ID")> _
    Public Property id As UInteger

    <Display(Name:="Serial Number")> _
    Public Property Srno As UInteger

    <Display(Name:="User Name")> _
    Public Property UserName As String

    <Display(Name:="Details")> _
    Public Property Details As String
  End Class
```

And My Controller is :

```
<HttpPost()> _
<AllowAnonymous()> _
<ValidateAntiForgeryToken()> _
Public Function EditReport(ByVal mdl As ReportsModel, ByVal FileUpl As HttpPostedFileBase ) As ActionResult

    Return View(mdl)
End Function
```

Here is my View:

```
<% Using Html.BeginForm() %>
    <%: Html.AntiForgeryToken() %>
    <%: Html.ValidationSummary(True) %>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>ReportsModel</legend>
        <%: Html.HiddenFor(Function(model) model.id) %>

        <div class="editor-label">
            <%: Html.LabelFor(Function(model) model.Srno) %>
        </div>
         <div class="editor-field">
            <%: Html.EditorFor(Function(model) model.Srno) %>
            <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(Function(model) model.Srno) %>
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            <%: Html.LabelFor(Function(model) model.UserName) %>
        </div>
         <div class="editor-field">
            <%: Html.EditorFor(Function(model) model.UserName) %>
            <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(Function(model) model.UserName) %>
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            <%: Html.LabelFor(Function(model) model.Details) %>
        </div>
         <div class="editor-field">
            <%: Html.EditorFor(Function(model) model.Details) %>
            <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(Function(model) model.Details) %>
        </div>

          <%--This Code Below is running correctly on passing it , But not with Reports Model--%>

        <form action="/phed/EditReport" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <label for="FileUpl1">Upload File: </label>
            <input type="file" name="FileUpl" id="FileUpl" />
            <span style="color: red;"><%:TempData("Message")%></span>


        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Save" />
        </p>
            </form>
    </fieldset>
<% End Using %>
```

**How to send this FileUpl along with ReportsModel to the controller ?** *I Can Not change reports Model.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it. I have Change the form action and enctype to "multipart/form-data". Like:

```
<div>
        <form action="/phed/EditReport" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
             <%: Html.AntiForgeryToken() %>
             <%: Html.ValidationSummary(True) %>
               <fieldset>
        <legend>ReportsModel</legend>

        <%: Html.HiddenFor(Function(model) model.id) %>
        <div class="editor-label">
            <%: Html.LabelFor(Function(model) model.Details) %>
        </div>
         <div class="editor-field">
            <%: Html.EditorFor(Function(model) model.Details) %>
            <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(Function(model) model.Details) %>
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            <%: Html.LabelFor(Function(model) model.BillsOfMonth) %>
        </div>
         <div class="editor-field">
            <%: Html.TextBox("BillsOfMonth", Model.BillsOfMonth, New With {Key .class = "monthpicker"})%>
            <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(Function(model) model.BillsOfMonth) %>
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            <%: Html.LabelFor(Function(model) model.UplDate) %>
        </div>

         <div class="editor-field">
             <%: Html.TextBox("UplDate", Model.UplDate, New With {Key .class = "datepicker"})%>
             <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(Function(model) model.UplDate) %>
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            <%: Html.LabelFor(Function(model) model.Authentication) %>
        </div>
         <div class="editor-field">
               <%: Html.DropDownList("Authentication", New List(Of SelectListItem) From { _
                            New SelectListItem With {.Text = "public", .Value = "public"}, _
                         New SelectListItem With {.Text = "private", .Value = "private"}})%>
             <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(Function(model) model.Authentication) %>
        </div>
        <div class="editor-label">
            <%: Html.LabelFor(Function(model) model.Download) %>
        </div>
         <div class="editor-field">
            <%: Html.TextBoxFor(Function(model) model.Download, New With {Key .readonly = "readonly"})%>
            <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(Function(model) model.Download) %>

        </div>
            <label for="FileUpl1">Upload File: </label>
            <input type="file" name="FileUpl" id="FileUpl" />
            <span style="color: red;"><%:TempData("Message")%></span>

          <input type="submit" class="sort-submit" value="Upload File" />

             </fieldset>
        </form>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you create a form nested to another form which is not allowed in HTML, so if you want to upload your file, you have to remove the second `Form`. The `BeginForm` method renders a form that will be handled by a controller action method.
You can use this method in a using block. In that case, the method renders the closing  tag at the end of the using block.
And you can do like this:

```
  <% Using Html.BeginForm("EditReport","phed",Nothing,FormMethod.Post, New With {.enctype="multipart/form-data"}) %>
   <%: Html.AntiForgeryToken() %>
   <%: Html.ValidationSummary(True) %>
   <fieldset>
     <legend>ReportsModel</legend>
      <%: Html.HiddenFor(Function(model) model.id) %>

      <div class="editor-label">
        <%: Html.LabelFor(Function(model) model.Srno) %>
      </div>
     <div class="editor-field">
        <%: Html.EditorFor(Function(model) model.Srno) %>
        <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(Function(model) model.Srno) %>
     </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        <%: Html.LabelFor(Function(model) model.UserName) %>
    </div>
     <div class="editor-field">
        <%: Html.EditorFor(Function(model) model.UserName) %>
        <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(Function(model) model.UserName) %>
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        <%: Html.LabelFor(Function(model) model.Details) %>
    </div>
     <div class="editor-field">
        <%: Html.EditorFor(Function(model) model.Details) %>
        <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(Function(model) model.Details) %>
    </div>

      <%--This Code Below is running correctly on passing it , But not with Reports Model--%>

        <label for="FileUpl1">Upload File: </label>
        <input type="file" name="FileUpl" id="FileUpl" />
        <span style="color: red;"><%:TempData("Message")%></span>


      <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Save" />
      </p>
     </fieldset>
  <% End Using %>
```

I hope it will help.